App hangs on actual hardware but not Android Studio
The app in question that my team and I created is here: https://codeberg.org/fbushstone/BasicFitness
When running the app on Android Studio's emulator, the runs normally with all the features we added. However, when attempting to run the app on an actual Android phone (Pixel 6a), the app hangs on the logo that Android shows when apps first run (i.e. we never make it past the initial loading screen of the featuring the clipart of the bicep).
Uninstalling and reinstalling does not fix the issue, and neither does rebuilding. Additionally, I tried signing the app. While that solved some problems, including allowing the app to actually install, the app can no longer proceed with execution. I was expecting the app to boot straight into the Workouts fragment.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to analyse logcat, find any exceptions or other error/warning entries. In android studio you can filter logcat with package:mine and see at what messages it stops. If no success, then consider adding logging in your app to see at which code lines it stops. If you can reproduce this problem with debug version, then consider debugging your code.

As per previous comments its hard to tell without any crash logs, but looking at your code, its probably because you have 2 databases being initialised in MainActivity. Each database initialisation is inside a synchronized block, which is a blocking thread. Real devices may take more time to load a database, this blocks the UI thread and makes your app hang, leading to an ANR. Consider changing the DB logic to be loaded in separate threads. But this is speculation given you have not provided exact logs.
